# change the variable in a forloop just like in list comprehension, python

Tags: python

I want to be able to change what something does in a for loop

here a very simple example

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

this will print 0 up to 9 and not include 10

and ofc i want 1 to 10 not 0 to 9

to fix this i would like to say:

```
i+1 for i in range(10):
     print(i)
```

but i cant

if i did list comprehension i can do:

```
list0 = [i+1 for i in range(10)]
```

this is very handy

now i have to either do

```
for i in range(1, 10+1):
```

which is very annoying

or do

```
print(i+1)
```

but if i used i 10 times i'd have to change them all

or i could say:

```
for i in range(10):
    i += 1
```

these methods are all not very nice, im just wondering if this neat way im looking for exists at all

thanks.

Comment: Short answer: no, you already present the two basic solutions for this. Python doesn't have any notion of pattern matching, so constructs such as `i + 1 = 11` to set `i` to `10` simply don't exist. You could use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) in conjugation with a lambda, but the complication that that would introduce would likely be less "nice" that what you've already covered.

Comment: Short answer: yes. Read what the official Python documentation says on [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Comment: @usr2564301 Can you please elaborate? What are you suggesting that is different from what the OP has already covered?

Comment: I fail to see the problem with `range(1, 10+1)` if what you actually need is the numbers 1 throught 10.

Comment: @Brian May be he meant to say do `range(1,10+1)`.

Comment: @Ch3steR you could always define two variables: start=1, end=10 and then: for i in range(start, end+1)

Comment: i + 1 is just an example, lets say i wanted to do something outside of numbers like make i be a string saying "this is number" + str(i)
then i couldnt just change the range, so then i'd need to do that some other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask if there exists any way to change the value received from an iterable in a `for` loop. The answer is yes; this can be accomplished in one of two ways. I'll continue to use your example with `range` to demonstrate this, but do note that I am in no way *suggesting* that these are ideal ways of solving that particular problem.

The first method is using the builtin [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
for i in map(lambda x: x + 1, range(10)):
```

`map` accepts a callable and an iterable, and will lazily apply the given callable to each element produced by the iterable. Do note that since this involves an additional function call during each iteration, this technique can incur a noticeable runtime penalty compared to performing the same action within the loop body.

The second method is using a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) (or, alternatively, any other flavor of list/set/dict compression):

```
for i in (x + 1 for x in range(10)):
```

As with `map`, using a generator will lazily produce transformed elements from the given iterable. Do note that if you opt to use a comprehension instead, the entire collection will be constructed upfront, which may be undesirable.

Again, for incrementing the values produced by `range`, neither of these are ideal. Simply using `range(1, 11)` is the natural solution for that.

Comment: ofc the i +1 was just an example, lets say i wanna do something complicated to that i, but i want to do it each time. then i'd have to change it under the for loop, but if this is slower then maybe doing it as the first step in the loop is just the best way, thanks for answering.